# Add class to a filtered element

Tags: jquery

I have some plugin-generated html that goes like this (I'm entering this manually, please don't mind the mistakes:

```
<div class="pluginoutput">
<p>PersonName</p>
<p>MyData</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
</div>

<div class="pluginoutput">
<p>PersonName</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
<p>Null</p>
</div>
```

What I need is way to hide DIVs containing less than four instances of "Null".

I have this variable that filters those that have 4 Nulls:

```
var m = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){return(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length == 4;});
```

And this that filters out the one that have less than four "Nulls":

```
var n = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){return(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length < 4;});
```

Now I want to hide n.
I tried

```
 $(n).addclass("hidden");
```

and

```
 $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){return(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length < 4;}).addClass("hidden");
```

but this doesn't work for some reason. What do I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Helpful tip, look into Chrome Dev Tools and learn about how to debug your code. A simple `console.log` would have shown you that those variables (m and n) didn't contain the values you were looking for.

Comment: @Valentin: Or better yet, rather than `console.log`, the debugger and inspecting things as you step through code.

Comment: in fact they do. I changed nothing to the code, except adding the $(variable).hide() as the first commenter suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your code. It should be `.addClass`.

```
 n.addClass("hidden");
```

and when it comes to hide them, You can simply use:

```
 n.hide()
```

Comment: Also note that `n` is *already* a jQuery object, no need to call `$()` on it again.

Answer (score 1):

In your `filter` callback, you're doing:

```
(this)
```

...where you probably wanted

```
$(this)
```

E.g.:

```
var n = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){return(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length < 4;});
// Need $ (with space in front) here ----------------------------------------^
```

You're also using `addclass` where you should be using `addClass`, and as `n` is *already* a jQuery instance, you don't want to call `$()` on it again.

So fix the `(this)` issue above, and then

```
n.addClass("hidden");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `this` to `$(this)`. You can also use `addClass()` after your filter directly:

```
var n = $('div.pluginoutput:contains("PersonName")').filter(function(){return  $(this).find('p:contains("Null")').length < 4;}).addClass("hidden");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dALn/1/)**